# Slide row of images up inside bootstrap panel-body on a loop using CSS

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, css-animations, slide

I'm relatively new to `bootstrap` and `CSS`. I'm having trouble with a slide up animation that I need to keep **inside** a `panel-body`. Ideally I'd like to accomplish this with just `CSS` and not `jQuery`.

If I have 36 thumbnails, I want to have a `panel-body` that "spins" (slides up) a row of 12 one-column images at a time and on a loop. Something like this (I'm using `angularjs`):

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="slideup">
        <!--this results in 36 divs that have an image-->
        <div ng-repeat="entity in entities" class="col-md-1">
            <img class="img-responsive" ng-src="{{ entity.logoUrl }}" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="panel-body">
    Anything inside this panel gets covered by the 24 remaining images which 
    should be invisible except when they're going through the visible
    "slideup" div in the panel-body above.
</div>
```

As I commented in the code, the problem is I can see the entire block of images sliding up, covering any content that might be below the div they're only supposed to be visible in.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the maximum height of the images?

Comment: Yep, they're going to be 150px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Hiding the overflow

You can prevent seeing the extra images simply enough with CSS by setting a fixed height on `div.slideup` and hiding any overflow:

```
.slideup {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 180px;
}
.slideup > div {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  height: 180px;
  padding: 0;
}
.slideup > div > img {
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

#### Scrolling

The code for the scrolling is mostly quite simple: you just need to adjust the `top` value for the `div.slideup` element on an interval. Since we're using angular, I'd do this by setting it to be the value of `$scope.offset`:

```
$scope.offset = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    $scope.offset += -10;
    $scope.$apply();
},
200);
```

#### Making the scrolling continuous

The trickiest part is with the continuous scrolling. To do this, you have to remove the images once they are out of view, then add them again to the bottom of your `$scope.entitities` array. At this time, you'll also need to reset the value of `$scope.offset`. All of this can be achieved with angular's `$scope.$watch`:

```
$scope.$watch('offset', function(newValue, oldValue, scope) {
  if (newValue == -180) {
    $scope.offset = 0;
    var removed = scope.entities.splice(0, 12);
    removed.forEach(function (item) {
      scope.entities.push(item);
    });
  }
});
```

See the code snippet below to see this in action.

```js
angular.module('app', []);
angular.module('app').controller('ctrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    var placeholder10 = {
      logoUrl: 'https://placehold.it/30x150'
    };

    var placeholder20 = {
      logoUrl: 'https://placehold.it/20x150'
    };

    $scope.entities = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
      $scope.entities.push(angular.copy(placeholder10));
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
      $scope.entities.push(angular.copy(placeholder20));
    }

    $scope.offset = 0;

    $scope.$watch('offset', function(newValue, oldValue, scope) {
      if (newValue == -180) {
        $scope.offset = 0;
        var removed = scope.entities.splice(0, 12);
        removed.forEach(function (item) {
          scope.entities.push(item);
        });
      }
    });

    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        $scope.offset += -10;
        $scope.$apply();
      },
      100);

  }
]);
```

```css
.slideup {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  height: 180px;
}
.slideup > div {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  height: 180px;
  padding: 0;
}
.slideup > div > img {
  height: 150px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl" class="panel-body">
  <div class="slideup row">
    <!--this results in 36 divs that have an image-->
    <div ng-repeat="entity in entities" class="col-xs-1" ng-style="{'top': offset + 'px'}">
      <img class="img-responsive" ng-src="{{ entity.logoUrl }}" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel-body">
  Anything inside this panel gets covered by the 24 remaining images which should be invisible except when they're going through the visible "slideup" div in the panel-body above.
</div>
```